# IP of client that connect to server

Tags: python, sockets, networking, ip, port

I have a socket that I connect by it to a web page and get something.

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('example.ir', 80))
mysock.send('GET http://example.ir/index.php HTTP/1.0\n\n')
while True:
    print"##########################"
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if ( len(data) < 1 ) :
        break
    print data

mysock.close()
```

Now, I like to know, what is the port and IP of mysock? 
What IP and port mysocket use to connect to example.ir?

Comment: Your example is broken.  It uses `socket.send` incorrectly.  It also speaks the HTTP protocol incorrectly.  Consider using a higher-level networking library that has fewer subtle traps and that implements boring low-level things like correct HTTP byte formatting for you.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone `\n` instead of `\r\n`? What is incorrect regarding the `socket.send`?

Comment: Regarding newlines, yes - HTTP lines are terminated by `\r\n`.  Regarding `socket.send`, there is no guarantee it sends the entire string passed to it.  It sends up to the entire string and returns the number of bytes it sent.  You have to check the return value and handle a short send by trying again with whatever bytes weren't sent.  Or use `socket.sendall`.  And I skipped mentioning the more subtle problems with the code, like the missing `EINTR` error handling code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the IP and port of mysock just do:

```
ip, port = mysock.getsockname()
```

Likewise, to get the same information about the peer it is connected to do:

```
ip, port = mysock.getpeername()  # 'example.ir', 80
```